# CS50 Wk4 Blur Pset

Tags: cs50

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red_total = 0;
            int blue_total = 0;
            int green_total = 0;
            int number_counted = 0;

            for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l++)
                {
                    if (i + k <= height && i + k >= 0 && j + l <= width && j + l >= 0)
                    {
                        blue_total += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtBlue;
                        red_total += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtRed;
                        green_total += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtGreen;
                        number_counted ++;
                    }
                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue_total / number_counted;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red_total / number_counted;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green_total / number_counted;

        }

    }
    return;
}
```

Why is that section && operators?

```
 if (i + k <= height && i + k >= 0 && j + l <= width && j + l >= 0)
```

I ran it with || operators because my understanding is that under the guise of the problem IF any of those conditions are satisfied there is no block to add. Yet why is it that when I run it under || it returns segmentation fault whereas if I run it with && the problem works out?

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

All of those conditions have to be true or else the array operations will be invalid.

e.g. if `i+k > height` then `image[i+k]` is invalid.

Also I think you have some "off by one problems. `image` is `[height][width]` so valid values are `[0..height-1]` and `[0..width-1]` so the checks should be more like `if (i + k < height && i + k >= 0 && j + l < width && j + l >= 0)`